# Teradata 15: [9134 : HY000] Teradata hour of day must be in range 1-12

Tags: sql, timestamp, teradata

I am trying to convert a varchar(19) timestamp field from a flat file into Teradata timestamp, but I got the following error.

```
select TOP 100 
TO_TIMESTAMP (SOURCE_DTTM ,  'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') AS TS1 
FROM "TEST"."CUSTOMER"
WHERE SOURCE_DTTM NOT LIKE '%0000-00-00%';



Executed as Single statement.  Failed [9134 : HY000] Teradata hour of day must be in range 1-12 
Elapsed time = 00:00:00.078 

STATEMENT 1: Select Statement failed.
```

I am wondering if there is a way to specify the timestamp as a 24 hour format.

Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I went to info.teradata.com and found the correct syntax:

```
select TOP 100 
TO_TIMESTAMP (SOURCE_DTTM ,  'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TS1 
FROM "TEST"."CUSTOMER"
WHERE SOURCE_DTTM NOT LIKE '%0000-00-00%';
```